# # of bit strings of length n (even>2), with n/2-1 zeros and n/2+1 ones, zero followed by one

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients, recursion

case 1:  What is the number of bit strings of length **4**, with **1** zero and **3** ones, zero **must** be followed by one

Answer: **3**

case 2: What is the number of bit strings of length **6**, with **2** zeros and **4** ones, zero **must** be followed by one

Answer: **6**

Question: What is the number of bit strings of length **n**, with **n/2-1** zeros and **n/2+1** ones, zero **must** be followed by one (*where n is even and n>2*)

Answer: **???**

Observation from the problem are: they all *end with one*, and *no 2 consecutive zeros* can occur

W/e you have in mind either recursion, closed form, permutation/combination or else anything helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k=n/2$. We will have $k-1$ blocks of $01$, and two extra $1$'s, in all $k+1$ "objects".

We **choose** where the extra $1$'s will go. This can be done in $\binom{k+1}{2}$ ways. We are essentially counting the strings of length $k+1$ made up of $k-1$ B's (block) and two E (extra $1$).

Comment: I guess problem becomes easy if you look at it as "# of ways put X objects into Y piles w/o order", idk why I didn't think of that, thanks

Comment: @SakhJack:  You are welcome. There are other ways, such as recurrence. But this one seems reasonably simple, and perhaps natural.

Comment: Would you be so kind to give a recurrence approach as another answer, if you have time? just curious

Comment: @SakhJack: Maybe. It is less pretty, so I will only do it if I find something neater than what I now have in mind.  The recurrence is $f(k+1)=f(k)+k+1$, $f(1)=1$.